# accessing data from a different class unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, getter

Hey guys I am new to Unity and finding it really hard to adapt to the concept of things. My problem is that I have a method that returns a string , and another method in a different class which calls on the method to get that string any time I try implement this the string is never accessed from the other class.

here is the method that returns the string

```
public string getString(){

 string hi  = "why hello";

 return hi;

}
```

And here is the method which prints the above string when a button is clicked

```
void OnMouseUp(){


firstScript log = (firstScript)FindObjectOfType(typeof(firstScript));

  string hello = log.getString()

print (hello);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference to the GameObject where you have the class on:

```
firstScript log =GameObject.find("NameOfGameObject").GetComponent<firstScript>();
Debug.Log(log.GetString());
```